# Isolating groups in regex match

Tags: regex

I have am writing a regular expression to return the version number of OpenSSH installed on a Windows machine, for our monitoring system. I have one of two strings:

```
version=OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
version=OpenSSH_7.1p1 Microsoft_Win32_port_with_VS Dec 22 2015, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

When the regex is:

```
\S+Windows_(\d.\d)
```

Then 7.7 is in group 1 and the monitoring system sees it. But when I try to cover the 7.1 string, the grouping gets messed up.

```
(\S+Windows_(\d.\d)|\S+OpenSSH_(\d.\d))
```

How can I modify that string to isolate group 3 and group 1 (for 7.1 and 7.7 respectively)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider changing the regex entirely so you only have one capture group.

Both digits you are trying to capture start with `version=OpenSSH_` with some optional characters in the middle.

Therefore you can do:

```
version=OpenSSH_\D*(\d\.\d)
```

Which will capture the correct version in either case. The advantage is you do not need to know which match group to use -- the return is always group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kVVVAM/3/)

If you want to use the alteration form that you have, that can be refactored a bit as well to have a single capture group:

```
(?:Windows_|\S+OpenSSH_)(\d.\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8eHoSC/1/)

Just know that format will have much more backtracking and may be 10x less efficient than the first form.

Answer (score 0):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:\S+Windows_(\d\.\d)|\S+OpenSSH_(\d\.\d))
```

[Try it out.](https://regex101.com/r/1E54Fu/1)

Comment: You should escape the `.` to get a literal `.` otherwise `\d.\d` matches with any character between two digits.

Comment: Oops! Thanks. Must… stop… rushing…

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(\S+Windows_)|(\S+OpenSSH_))(\d+\.\d+)
```

You can split up the groups like this, than it's always in the same group (in group3),the (?:) is a non capturing group.
https://regex101.com/r/ZgtiYo/3

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, this problem has more solutions. The interesting thing about the regex you tried is the creation of more than needed capturing groups inside the set. There is a specific structure you can use to tackle with this (if supported): [Branch Reset Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

Essentially capturing groups inside a branch reset group are shared between all the options, think of it as a sort of advance backtracking, where groups are reused.

This is the new regex:

```
((?|\S+OpenSSH_(\d\.\d)|\S+Windows_(\d\.\d)))
```